# query optimization delete nested query

Tags: mysql, optimization, performance, query-performance

Can the following query be optimized ?

```
DELETE FROM COLOR_TAGS 
WHERE COLOR_PROJECTID = $id 
AND NoteID IN(
SELECT ID FROM note_note 
WHERE BibID=$bid AND isdel=0);
```

Comment: Is it suboptimal?  If yes, how?  Please, make your questions a bit more meaningful by adding detail.  If you don't provide us with details, the best answer is 'Probably yes/no'.  Until then, I place a -1 vote.

Comment: possible duplicate of [query optimization for update nested query IN(SELECT](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23954/query-optimization-for-update-nested-query-inselect)

Answer (score 4):

Add composite indexes to your tables:

On `COLOR_TAGS`, index `(COLOR_PROJECTID, NoteID)`

On `note_note`, index `(isdel, BibID, ID)`.